# Binding a key-sequence to a command in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to bind key-sequence `C-tab` to `indent-rigidly`. It works when I do it interactively after `M-x local-set-key` . But I want it to be applied every time Emacs is started.  For this I added following line in my `init.el` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-tab") (indent-rigidly))
```

(as explained on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Binding-keys-to-commands.html)

However, it does not work. 'local-set-key' in above line also does not work. "C-TAB" also does not work. The error message is:

```
<C-tab> is undefined
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: `(indent-rigidly)` -- as used by you -- and `(quote indent-rigidly)` -- using the general format explained on the page you've linked to -- are *not* equivalent. The latter is unexpectedly verbose, mind -- the usual way of writing `(quote indent-rigidly)`, and what you are likely to see elsewhere, is `'indent-rigidly`

Answer (score 3):

The command needs to be quoted. The following are equivalent (and should work):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") 'indent-rigidly)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") (quote indent-rigidly))
```

Comment: I am still getting message `<C-tab> is undefined`. On running from command line: "emacs --debug-init", the error is shown to be: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "C- must prefix a single character, not tab")`

Answer (score 1):

Pass to `kbd` exactly the key description you see in the error message: `"<C-tab>"`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'indent-rigidly)
```

`M-x global-set-key` lets you hit the key sequence directly, without knowing how to describe it. And `C-h k` followed by the key sequence shows you exactly how Emacs describes it - in this case, it shows you `<C-tab>`.

However, it turns out that `(kbd "C-<tab>")` and `(kbd "<C-tab>")` return the same thing: `[C-tab]`. So you probably have some other problem going on.

What does `C-h k` tell you, when you hit the key sequence you think you want? Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

---

[BTW, if you don't want to fiddle with and be bothered by the (totally unnecessary) use of angle brackets by Emacs for key descriptions, you can just use library [**`naked.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NaKeD) and do without them: **`(naked "C-tab")`** = `(kbd "<C-tab>")` = `(kbd "C-<tab>")`.]

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is:

```
(global-set-key [(control tab)] 'indent-rigidly)
```

or:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") 'indent-rigidly)`